# `iptables-restore` does not preserve custom chains

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I am using `iptables v1.6.0` on Slackware 14.2.
I have some iptables filter rules which use custom chains. Sample output from
`iptables-save` may look like

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP - [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP - [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP - [0:0]
:custom_chain - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j custom_chain
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A custom_chain -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

According to the man page of `iptables-restore` the `-n` option should leave the current ruleset intact and only append the new rules.

```
-n, --noflush
    don't flush the previous contents of the table.  If  not
    specified,both commands flush (delete) all previous contents
    of the respective table.
```

However, if I try to add rules like

```
# cat new_rules
*filter
:INPUT DROP - [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP - [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP - [0:0]
:custom_chain - [0:0]
:new_chain - [0:0]
-A new_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

by using `iptables-restore` with the `-n` option and check the ruleset with `iptables-save`

```
# iptables-restore -n < new_rules
# iptables-save
*filter
:INPUT DROP - [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP - [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP - [0:0]
:custom_chain - [0:0]
:new_chain - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j custom_chain
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A new_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

then the default chains stay intact but the custom chain is flushed in spite of the `-n` option. Is there a way to preserve the old custom chains? If this is not a bug then what is the reasoning behing this behavior?

**UPDATE**

Further investigation shows that custom chains are only flushed if they are explicitly mentioned in the `new_rules` file. However, this does not solve the problem since it is still impossible to append a rule to a preexisting custom chain. `iptables-restore -n < new_rules` would still flush and lose all previous rules in that custom chain, thus leaving only the one rule that was supposed to be appended in addition.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this bug  on Debian. I took your exact examples, with a pair of `*filter`/`COMMIT` around to have a correct syntax. Not with iptables 1.6.0+snapshot20161117-6 nor older 1.4.21-2+b1 . Not on kernel 4.12.8 nor kernel 4.9.50. I always get both `-A custom_chain -j ACCEPT` and `-A new_chain -j DROP` as expected.

Comment: @A.B Sorry about the missing `*filter/COMMIT` lines. But this is not the cause of the problem. While copy/pasting I forgot another line in the `new_rules` file, the one which declares the `:custom_chain`. This, however, led to some further insight of the problem. Please see my update for a more detailed explanation. Thanks for your time and effort to investigate.

Comment: Do those custom chains contain fancy rules or just a list of allowed IPs/ports? If it's the latter, you could avoid this problem by using ipsets (as well as improve performance).

Comment: Did you fix your problem? Thanks to your question, I learned about the "-n" parameter by searching "iptables-restore preserve existing rules" on DuckDuckGo, which worked great on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same bug.
Looking at https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/iptables/ip6tables-restore.c?id=577b7e20c2af1e6ea2bbe72e0c01802334fa4069

It seems nautical was right

```
            if (ops->builtin(chain, handle) <= 0) {
            if (noflush && ops->is_chain(chain, handle)) {
                DEBUGP("Flushing existing user defined chain '%s'\n", chain);
                if (!ops->flush_entries(chain, handle))
                    xtables_error(PARAMETER_PROBLEM,
                           "error flushing chain "
                           "'%s':%s\n", chain,
                           strerror(errno));
```

Since this is not a builtin chain and noflush is 1, iptables-restore will flush the custom table.

Answer (score 0):

First: you shoudn't use iptables-restore the way you are trying here, there's certainly a better, safer, more elegant solution. Perhaps with grawity's suggestion by using ipset, or by having a specific chain that can afford to be deleted.

I don't see a bug anywhere.

Just consider that `:` are "chain creation" definitions. By using `-n` this chain is not destroyed, so there's no need to define it again. If it's not redefined, it's not erased along with its contents.

So, to preserve the old custom_chain, try this as new_rules file:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP - [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP - [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP - [0:0]
:new_chain - [0:0]
-A new_chain -j DROP
-A custom_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

result when you had the initial rules and then apply new_rules:

```
# iptables-restore -n < new_rules
# iptables-save
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:custom_chain - [0:0]
:new_chain - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j custom_chain
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A custom_chain -j ACCEPT
-A custom_chain -j DROP
-A new_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

custom_chain had more content added and the previous content was preserved: that's what you wanted.

Of course now you can't use the new_rules file alone (without `-n`), you would get an error because `custom_chain` is not defined.

You can even fragment your rules used with `-n` into a file with rules actually overwritting existing chains, and the other one that wouldn't if it's more manageable (but again... don't).

new_rule1:

```
*filter
:new_chain - [0:0]
-A new_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

new_rule2:

```
*filter
-A custom_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Applying both (using `-n` with both) after the previous new_rules would now give:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:custom_chain - [0:0]
:new_chain - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j custom_chain
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A custom_chain -j ACCEPT
-A custom_chain -j DROP
-A custom_chain -j DROP
-A new_chain -j DROP
COMMIT
```

but instead of going this way, maybe using plain old iptables commands directly is preferable.